# keyPressEvent not printing when clicking button in Calculator UI PySide2

Tags: python, user-interface, qt-designer, pyside2

I am beginner and following a course on Python GUIs. This time he is teaching a GUI done on QT designer and then translated to python code using PySide.
The problem is that the event is not printed if I click one button.

Link to see translated PySide2 ui_calculadora.py below: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G3xXnz1WBSdns8gLkFNwcwAkwZXdOqrL/view?usp=sharing

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from VISTA.ui_calculadora import Ui_Calculadora
 
 
class Calculadora(QDialog):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(Calculadora, self).__init__()
        self.calculadora = Ui_Calculadora()
        self.calculadora.setupUi(self)
    
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print('Key: ' + str(event.key()) + ' | Text Press: ' + str(event.text()))
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("----Example Starts----")
 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mi_aplicacion = Calculadora()
    mi_aplicacion.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc I have edited the question and added a link to the translated PySide2 .py file.

Comment: @RafaelLainez "The problem is that the event is not printed if I click one button." What do you mean? If you click on a button, you certainly don't get a *keyboard* event. If what you mean is that the keyPress doesn't get called when the focus is on the QLineEdit, then it's absolutely normal: the widget has focus, and it "eats" all keyboard events, because since a QLineEdit uses key events, those events should *not* be propagated to the parent.

Comment: @musicamante You are totally right I now did understood the problem. Thanks for the help.